# Add Sheet Name as Date and Increment date every run

Tags: excel, vba

I use an Excel macro to add sheet name as date. It works.

I want to make it increment on a daily basis.

For example today on 28-09-2018 I click on the button to add a sheet. The next day when I click the button it should add a sheet with the name of 29-09-2018 without getting value from the cell reference.

```
Sub datesheets()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

For Each w In Worksheets
    If w.Name = "26.09.2018" Then
        found = True
        Workbook.Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = "26.09.2018" + i
    End If
Next
If found = False Then
        Worksheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = "26.09.2018"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the way that the date is listed - now, the date is based on todays’s date which you get from the `Now()` function. Using `DateAdd()` I was able to tell it to add a new sheet with tomorrow’s date.

I also changed the first `Worksheets.Add(...)` call to place the new day’s sheet immediately after the previous day’s, because that seemed like what you intended to happen.

```
Sub datesheets()

    Dim found As Boolean

    Dim w As Worksheet
    For Each w In Worksheets
        If w.Name = Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") Then
            found = True

            Worksheets.Add(, w).Name = Format(DateAdd("d", 1, Now()), "dd.mm.yyyy")
        End If
    Next w

    If found = False Then
        Worksheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Let me know if this doesn’t work - I did it on my phone so it’s liable to have a typo or two

Comment: Workbook.Sheets.Add(, w).Name = Format(DateAdd(Now(), ”d”, 1), "dd.mm.yyyy")

Comment: Now bro its giving an error of object required error # 424 on the line Set wTemp = Workbook.sheets.add(,w)

Comment: @Usman.haiderBhatti lol it was actually from the unicode `”` character that my phone used for quotes. vba will only accept `"`

Comment: so bro is it possible or not?

Comment: bro its working and add up only date. like 29.09.2018 and 30.09.2018 after that its giving error "Name already Exist" for the date of 30.09.2018.

Comment: Is there any solution  of this problem?

Comment: @Usman.haiderBhatti How many days do you want it to add? Just today and tomorrow?

Comment: No I want to add continuous days from today to tomorrow and next day and next and it will add every time a sheet with increment of date every time when I press the button.

Comment: @Usman.haiderBhatti Oh, well that's really pretty different from what I got from the initial question. I think you should post that last comment with a little bit more explanation as a new question